# How to generate random events in android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, random, generator

I have a an array of objects and would like to be able to randomly choose one from the list when a button is pressed. How would you do that in Android?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? What kind of objects are these?

Answer (score 5):

Do something like this inside your onClickListener

```
Random rand = new Random();
int selector = rand.nextInt(yourList.length);
yourList.get(selector);
```

Something like that.

EDIT: Actually if it is an ArrayList then it will be more like this

```
Random rand = new Random();
int selector = rand.nextInt(yourList.size());
yourList.get(selector);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use java.util.random.

It's basically plain java at this point.  You can use java.util.nextInteger().

Comment: To clarify, that is `java.util.Random` and the `nextInt()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you are looking for?

```
Random r = new Random();
E element;
int rand = r.nextInt(array.length);
element = array[rand];
```