# How to generate a random class result from a button using onClick for android?

Tags: java, android, random, android-intent

If you have three classes; Red, Blue, Green. If you were to click on a button from the main class activity, how would you have that onClick randomly select a class to be the new activity?

For example:

```
Button random;
random = (Button)findViewById(R.id.random);
random.setOnClickListener(phaseHandler);
View.OnClickListener phaseHandler = new View.OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(random.getId() == ((Button)v).getId()){
        Intent i = new Intent(context, (Select one class randomly from classes Blue,     Red, Green);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Random rand = new Random(); 
int pickedNumber = rand.nextInt(3);
if(pickedNumber==0){//Class Red}
else if(pickedNumber==1){//Class Blue}
else{//Class Green}
```

Comment: Thanks so much man. It works! I've just learned that I need a better thought process as I was close to your solution but I completely forgot you can just enclose if statements and follow with the new Intent activity.

Answer (score 3):

You can use java.util.Random. Have the classes in a collection for example, take nextInt() from Random and have it return the class from the collection to be passed on to your method.

This question is very similar to yours, have a look:
[How to generate random events in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654130/how-to-generate-random-events-in-android)

Comment: Use a switch/case statement to differentiate between them